# React Native Android crashes on enabling debug mode

Tags: android, react-native, debugging

Shaking the android device and hit Debug, and it crashes every time right away. From the Android Studio logcat, it shows **No source URL loaded, have you initialised the instance?**:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: No source URL loaded, have you initialised the instance?
    at com.facebook.infer.annotation.Assertions.assertNotNull(Assertions.java:35)
    at com.facebook.react.modules.debug.SourceCodeModule.getTypedExportedConstants(SourceCodeModule.java:39)
    at com.facebook.fbreact.specs.NativeSourceCodeSpec.getConstants(NativeSourceCodeSpec.java:35)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.getConstants(JavaModuleWrapper.java:129)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

The same react native codebase, turning on dubug mode on ios is working fine, but on Android it always crash when debug mode is turned on. I can't see what's causing it by the error log.

Here are the dependencies I have for the react native app, and I'm using redux and redux-devtools-extension for debugging. Am I missing any libraries?

```
"dependencies": {
  "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.14",
  "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.7.0",
  "expo": "~42.0.1",
  "expo-permissions": "12.1.0",
  "expo-splash-screen": "~0.11.2",
  "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
  "expo-updates": "~0.8.1",
  "react": "17.0.2",
  "react-dom": "17.0.2",
  "react-native": "0.64.1",
  "react-native-fast-image": "^8.5.11",
  "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
  "react-native-navigation": "^7.14.0",
  "react-native-reanimated": "~2.1.0",
  "react-native-screens": "3.2.0",
  "react-native-unimodules": "~0.13.3",
  "react-native-web": "0.16.3",
  "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
  "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
  "tslint": "^6.1.3",
  "tslint-react": "^5.0.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
  "@types/react": "17.0.5",
  "@types/react-native": "0.64.5",
  "babel-preset-expo": "~8.3.0",
  "jest-expo": "~41.0.0",
  "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
  "typescript": "4.2.4"
},
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some more search arounds, found this is a known issue in react-native-reanimated. As their [website](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/2.2.0/installation/#installing-the-package) points out

> Please note that Reanimated 2 doesn't support remote debugging, only
> Flipper can be used for debugging.

Another [github issue](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/1990#issuecomment-831888705) also pointed out this issue

> This is expected, you can't use remote debugging with turbomodules
> (which Reanimated v2 is using). Check out Flipper to debug your app.
>
> https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/#known-problems-and-limitations

https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/1990

Removing this library fixed the issue.

1. Remove the react-native-reanimated dependency in package.json
2. Remove related code in android's MainApplication.java
3. yarn install or npm install
4. Go to the ios folder and run `pod install`
5. Go the the android folder and run `./gradlew clean`
6. Rebuild the app. `yarn android` and `yarn ios`

Another alternative is to use Flipper for debugging instead.

Comment: what if you really need the library to be there, as in the case where it's required by @react-navigation/drawer?

Comment: That will be a choice you would have to make for yourself. Give up the debug mode and keep using react-native-reanimated and @react-navigation/drawer. Or find an alternative for @react-navigation/drawer which doesn't need react-native-reanimated

Comment: I was able to fix this issue by upgrading `react-native-reanimated` to `2.4.1`.

Comment: @Vadim unfortunately, it did not work for me. :-\ @s-hunter, devs on live enterprise apps don't have the luxury to "choose debugging or this module." Although, it is worth considering an alternative to `rn-drawer`.

Comment: I've uninstalled react-native-reanimated package but it still crashes. I'm using expo, but don't have the android folder.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading `react-native-reanimated` to `2.4.1` may fix this issue.

Comment: Upgrading `react-native-reanimated` does resolve the crash issue on debug, thanks.

Comment: @TommyLeong does it affecting old code?