# Remote Debugger didn’t work for React Native Application

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to test remote debugging for my React Native application. But the app is closed itself after clicking on the Remote Debug JS from the popup window after clicking CRTL + M.

This is the error message shown from my android emulator after enable remote debugging:

[image: Error Message from Android Emulator]

Does anyone know how to solve it? I had been stuck on this issue a long time ago.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native Android crashes on enabling debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70405285/react-native-android-crashes-on-enabling-debug-mode)